# Multiply a function curve

Tags: matlab

I used `fit()` function to fit a curve to my dataset. Then I want to calculate integral of this function, so I'm using `integrate()`. Everything works, I've got a result. Now I'd like to calculate integral from function like this: `x*fun`, where fun is the result of `fit()` function. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not pre-multiply the _y_ values that you pass to `fit()` by _x_ and than integrate the resulting function?

Comment: Ok, that's a solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have it the way you stated, you could do something like this

```
%I'm making up a function
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = x.^2;
[ft, ~] = fit( x, y, 'poly2' );

%Put in the new formula, the formula() function puts out the formula as a string and then just pre- and append a "x*"
fitType = fittype(['x*(',formula(ft),')']);

%You need the values from the original fit, to put into the new fit, the cell array is so Matlab will read them as separate inputs
coeff = num2cell(coeffvalues(ft));

%Make the fit
NewFit = cfit(fitType, coeff{:});

%Now it's just what you did before
plot(integrate(NewFit, x, min(x))
```